# Set-ADuser extensionAttribute won't work but things like title will

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a simple script that takes an already created user and updates an attribute based on what the admin put in.

The code works just fine if I replace `extensionAttribute` with for example `title` or something like that, but it won't with extensionAttributes.

I have tried a few things and other extensionAttributes but the code is so simple and it works with other Attributes. I am guess extensionAttributes require a bit more in the code that I am missing.

```
$name = Read-Host "AD Logon Name"
$key = Read-Host "Azure Key"
Set-ADUser $name -extensionAttribute6 $key -PassThru
```

> Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'extensionAttribute6'

Even though it exists it is not finding it.

Answer (score 4):

`Set-ADUser` has a limited set of parameters covering the most commonly used attributes in AD. However, given the sheer amount of existing attributes and the fact that the AD schema is extensible, an attempt to have all attributes represented as parameters just wouldn't be feasible.

For attributes that are not represented as parameters use the parameter `-Add` or `-Replace` with a hashtable argument.

```
Set-ADUser $name -Replace @{'extensionAttribute6' = $key} -PassThru
```

Comment: thank you for the info. That will help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but this worked for me:

```
    Import-Csv -Path "C:\data\12345.csv" |ForEach-Object {
    Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName -replace @{
    description = "$($_.description)"
    extensionAttribute1 = "$($_.extensionAttribute1)"
    extensionAttribute3 = "$($_.extensionAttribute3)"
    initials = "$($_.initials)";
    #additionalAttributeName = "$($_.additionalAttributeName)"
    #additionalAttributeName = "$($_.additionalAttributeName)"
    #additionalAttributeName = "$($_.additionalAttributeName)"
    #additionalAttributeName = "$($_.additionalAttributeName)"
    #additionalAttributeName = "$($_.additionalAttributeName)"
    }
    }
```

The top row of your .csv file would look like the following for this example:

```
samAccountname,description,extensionAttribute1,extensionAttribute3,initials
```